# XTestFakeButtonEvent not defined, how to find the right includes?

Tags: include, header-files, xlib

I'm writing some C code using the X11 API, and want to use the function `XTestFakeButtonEvent`.

According to the [docs](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXtst/xtestlib.html#C_Language_Binding) I'd need to include `<X11/extensions/XTest.h>`.

I had to install `libXtst-devel` to be able to include it.

However, when I compile I still get this error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4pbNhk.o: in function `main':
mouse-chording.c:(.text+0x7bf): undefined reference to `XTestFakeButtonEvent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is `libXtst-devel` not the right package?

I compile with the following command:

```
gcc mouse-chording.c -o mouse-chording.exe -lX11
```

`#include "X11/Xlib.h"` was not enough, appearently, I also needed to add `-lX11` to the compilation command.

Do I have to do something similar for `XTest`?

Using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with XFCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked what `xdotool` does, since it is using the same library.

The Makefile has `-lXtst` so I added this to the make command and it works.

The inconsistency in naming is kind of confusing though; XTest, libXtst, and lXtst